# JavaScript array objects to one-column csv string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to convert my array into a string using only one of the properties of each object?

**Given:**

```
[{f1:'v1', f2:'v21'}, {f1:'v2', f2:'v22'}, {f1:'v3', f2:'v23'}]
```

**Desired**

```
'v21,v22,v23'
```

Comment: how do you chose which property is the correct one ?

Comment: oops, had an error in JSON, want to use f2 property

Answer (score 2):

```js
let input = [{
  f1: 'v1',
  f2: 'v21'
}, {
  f1: 'v2',
  f2: 'v22'
}, {
  f1: 'v3',
  f2: 'v23'
}];
let output = input.map((item) => item.f2).join(',');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You need to put the values of `f1`, `f2` etc in quotes

Comment: wouldn't it be better with `reduce` ?

Comment: That's probably a matter of preference. I think the combination of `map` and `join` is reasonably clean.

Comment: The only thing to be careful of with this, IE doesn't support lambda's(`=>`) or `let`'s, so if this is running on the client and you need to support IE, you may need to re-write this with a normal `function` and `var`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var arr = [{"f1":"v1","f2":"v21"},{"f1":"v2","f2":"v22"},{"f1":"v3","f2":"v23"}];

var res = arr.reduce((a, e)=>{a.push(e.f2); return a },[]).toString()

console.log(res)
```